# Why is MKMapView not loading overlays on initial app start?

Tags: ios, deployment, delegates, mkmapview, overlays

Why isn't `MKMapView` loading overlays, if it's the initial start (right after deployment) of the app and the `MKMapView` is in the first View?

Afterwards everything works fine, even if it's the initial start of the app and the `MKMapView` is not the first view.

The following delegates are not being called:

`mapView: viewForOverlay:`

`mapView: viewForAnnotation:`

I'm using SDK 5.1 and Storyboard for the UI.

Comment: anybody? It seems to be a serious issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data for the overlays is not available right after the initial start, it's not available for drawing either.

**Update Approach:**

Instead of just adding the objects only in viewDidLoad I switched it to a more dynamic approach.

The most obvious way of doing this is to use `NSFetchedResultController`, known from `UITableViewController`. It has a handy delegate which calls my viewcontroller if something changed.

So from now I only implement the delegate methods and then update, remove or delete the overlays from the `MKMapView`.